# Firebase authentication with React Redux Redux-Thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-redux

I'm trying to use firebase for authentication in my react redux app.
I want to redirect user to next page on successful login but I'm getting the error when I submit the login form

**Error**

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

**Handle Submit function in LoginForm**

```
handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.email !== '' && this.props.password !== '') {
      this.props.loginUser(this.props.email, this.props.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.context.router.push('/posts');
      });
    } else {
      console.log('empty');
    }
  }
```

**Action Creator**

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('failed to sign in');
        return;
      });
  };
}


export function loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user) {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
}
```

**The authentication works if I remove the then from handle submit function but I don't know how to redirect user to next page ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by including a return inside the dispatch. I'm putting the updated code here for future visitors.

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('failed to sign in');
        return;
      });
  };
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes this is the solution I was going to post. The reason you were getting the error is you weren't returning a Promise.

Answer (score 0):

OP didn't mention it, but for those using [`react-redux-firebase`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-firebase) and it's [integration with redux-thunk](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/integrations/thunks.html), it would look like so:

```
export function loginUser(email, password) {
  return (dispatch, { getFirebase }) => {
    return getFirebase()
      .login({ email, password }
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('failed to sign in');
        return;
      });
  };
}
```

That said, login should be able to be called directly in your components if you are using `firebaseConnect` or `withFirebase` as shown in [the auth section of the docs](http://docs.react-redux-firebase.com/history/v2.0.0/docs/recipes/auth.html).